# Memory leak using ARC GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, gpuimage

I'm trying to do processing on an image in another .m file. Currently the following is my code. I have a global NSMutableArray to store two UIImages and process the two. Every time the user clicks a button, it will take two pictures store them in the global array process them and then remove the elements. I am using ARC, so no releasing is required by me.

```
@implementation
NSMutableArray * imagesArray;
ImageProcessor *imageProcessor;
...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
imageProcessor = [[ImageProcessor alloc] init];
//some other code
}

-(UIImage*)processImages{//process images using GPUImage
    UIImage *firstImg = [[imagesArray objectAtIndex:1] copy];
    UIImage *secImg = [[imagesArray objectAtIndex:0] copy];
    UIImage *processedImage = [imageProcessor flashSubtract:firstImg : secImg];
    UIImage *dividedImage = [imageProcessor referenceDivide:processedImage];
//    [self uploadDropbox:UIImagePNGRepresentation(processedImage) : @"Output.png"];//try to save tiff files
    //using ARC, no explicit memory releasing required
    NSLog(@"image processed!");
    [imagesArray removeAllObjects];
    return dividedImage;
}
```

ImageProcessor.m:

```
#import "ImageProcessor.h"

@interface ImageProcessor ()

@end

@implementation ImageProcessor

GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter *subFilter;
GPUImageDivideBlendFilter* divFilter;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    //initialize filters
    subFilter = [[GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter alloc] init];
    divFilter = [[GPUImageDivideBlendFilter alloc] init];
    return self;
}

-(UIImage*)flashSubtract:(UIImage*) image1 : (UIImage*) image2{
    UIImage *processedImage;
//    @autoreleasepool {

    //CAUSING MEMORY ISSUE
    GPUImagePicture *img1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image1];//image with flash
    GPUImagePicture *img2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image2];//image without flash
    //MEMORY ISSUE END

    [img1 addTarget:subFilter];
    [img2 addTarget:subFilter];

    [img1 processImage];
    [img2 processImage];
    [subFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    processedImage = [subFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

//    }

    //consider modifications to filter possibly?


    return processedImage;
}
@end
```

I'm getting a memory leak issue where after [imageProcessor flashSubtract] it doesn't deallocate memory. Memory usage keeps growing and after around 30 pictures, the app crashes. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I was testing with that __weak, was really just exhausting options, since I'm fairly new to objective c. yea I feel like using the nsmutable array might have something to do with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest running your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu, or press <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>), which can be useful in identifying issues in Objective-C code. Make sure you have a clean bill of health from the Analyzer before proceeding. With ARC, there might not be too many issues here, but it's worth checking, just to make sure.

Second, when you get a leak report, that's not necessarily what caused the leak. It's just showing you where the leaked object was originally created, so you can then go through your code and figure out why that particular object leaked. For example, I ran an example through "Leaks" and it directed me to this routine:

[image]

That isn't terribly illuminating. It's nice to know what leaked, but I'd rather find out why the object leaked, not just where the leaked object was originally allocated.

But when I ran the app (not through Instruments, but just run it in the debugger) and tapped on the "Debug memory graph" button, [image], I could then tap on my object that should have been released in the left panel and I can now see what object is maintaining the strong reference. In this case, I can see the strong reference cycle that I had accidentally established:

[image]

Armed with this information, I can track down where these strong references were established and figure out why they are still present. Or, in this example, I would track down why I have a strong reference cycle and figure out which of those references need to be `weak`.

Comment: This was really helpful! I ran the Build analyzer and realized that I am not properly releasing my Core image objects such as CGImageRef objects. It seems that these still need to be released using specific CFRelease functions even with ARC enabled. Thank you so much!